# Using a method return in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods, return

I can't figure out how to put the return of a method into a string. I had thought it would look like this,

```
def cat
 puts "Purrrrr..."
end

puts "The cat says #{cat}."
```

but this is not working. I also tried

```
puts "The cat says %s." % cat
```

and

```
puts "The cat says #{return.cat}."
```

also

```
puts "The cat says #{send.cat}."
```

I kept trying stuff and looking things up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is working :

```
def cat
  "Purrrrr..."
end

puts "The cat says #{cat}."
# >> The cat says Purrrrr....
```

Why the below one is not giving the output as above :

```
def cat
 puts "Purrrrr..."
end

puts "The cat says #{cat}."
# >> Purrrrr...
# >> The cat says .
```

This is because you used `puts "Purrrrr..."` inside the method `#cat`. Now, inside the string interpolation method `#cat` has been called, and `puts` prints the the string `"Purrrrr..."` and returns `nil`. So `puts "The cat says #{cat}."` became `puts "The cat says #{nil}."`. Which results the output as :

```
The cat says .
            ^
```

`"#{nil}"` evaluates to an empty string(`""`). So the output is not as expected by you.

```
(arup~>~)$ irb
2.0.0-p0 :001 > nil.to_s
 => "" 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > "foo #{nil}"
 => "foo " 
2.0.0-p0 :003 >
```

`puts "The cat says #{return.cat}."` and `puts "The cat says #{send.cat}."` are invalid ruby code, they will throw error. So *Don't try this!*

Hope it helps!

Comment: hmmm, that makes sense, but is there a way to call the method in a string, if it is a string, like the "purrrr..." ?

Comment: LOL, just saw what happened clearly, sorry, very confusing this stuff is!

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you don't have to return a value explicitly. Last line result in a method will be returned by default.

In this case, the return value of 'puts' method is nil. So the return value of method 'cat' is nil.

If you are looking for a return string, you can just put a string at the last line of the method 'cat' as @Arup suggested. That will work.